# Pass JSON object vs JSON string in HTTP POST

Tags: json, http

I'm building a REST API in JAVA and C# and I was wondering about the way I should pass data to those services.

What I'm familiar with as the right way is to send JSON object as the data in the POST body:

```
{name:'Dor'}
```

but I can also pass a string and parse the JSON in my service:

```
'{name:'Dor'}'
```

What is the preferable way from performance factor? or any other factors?

Comment: Server will have to parse the request payload anyway, so better opt for the first solution.

Comment: @sp00m Will the payload parsing as string will be quicker than JSON?

Comment: I guess yes, but you'll have to parse the JSON afterwards anyway. Which means that you'll have *time_parsing_string + time_parsing_json* instead of *time_parsing_json* only. Furthermore, it looks like [premature optimization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/80092/72730) `;)`

Comment: There is no such thing like a "String" as a payload in an HTTP request. The HTTP request requires you to send "data" which is interpreted as specified by the `Content-Type` header. JSON is send _AS IS_, as a sequence of Unicode characters, most often it is UTF-8. The corresponding content type (MIME type) is (most appropriate) `application/json`. If you want to send a string, you should send it as `text/plain; charset=utf-8` including the character encoding.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper so what do you think? is there a preferable way to send the data?

Comment: @DorCohen Yes, JSON should be send as JSON (using `application/json` as content-type. However, your application rarely deals with JSON directly. Usually, you use a Web application framework (ASP.net) and a JSON library (e.g. Newton soft). In your app you deal with C# objects. JSON is just a transport format and an implementation detail. You could use XML or YAML or other formats as well. Web application frameworks let you switch between JSON and XML without affecting your application logic.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you need to send the json data across via jquery, then we need to use stringify, else the data would be serialized into to key=value pair.

So, you cannot send the json object directly via jquery ajax method.
How it works behind the hood:

In $.ajax function, if we provide data as

```
data :{key1:"value1", key2:"value2"}
is serialized to key1=value1&key2=value2
```

if we provide data as

```
data :'{key1:"value1", key2:"value2"}' or JSON.stringify({key1:"value1", key2:"value2"})
is sent as {key1:"value1", key2:"value2"}
```

So, what we can conclude is that, we cannot pass json object directly via jquery, we can send only json string. Hope this clarifies everyone.

Comment: Since the HTTP request body is ultimately a sequence of bytes, your JS object will have to be serialised to JSON anyway when the request will be created. So, it's not "better" nor has it better performance. You just don't see what's exactly being performed under the hood.

Comment: check my above modified ans.